# Variational Principle for Combined Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle

I have a quantum mechanical system with the following potential: $$V(x) = \frac{b^2}{x^2}-\frac{b}{x}.$$ I want to use the variational principle to estimate the ground state energy.

I estimate my wavefunction as $x e^{-ax^2}$. This ensures that at $x=0$, we don't get a
blow up for the function, and it also ensures convergence of the integral when we take the range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

However, in the official solutions, the wave function is estimated as $x e^{-ax}$ and the range is taken from $0$ to $\infty$ due to the blow up of the integral.

How do I know in the variational principle what is the correct estimate for the wave function?

Comment: "However, in the official solutions..." Are the official solutions perhaps directed towards a potential that depends on the radial distance from the origin $r$ (which only runs from 0 to infinity)?

Comment: The variational principle is all based on choosing an Ansatz. If the Ansatz is bad, the ground state energy will also be approximated badly. Obviously, the more the trial function looks like the exact ground state, the better will be the estimate obtained from the variation. To my knowledge, there is no systematic way to come up with an Ansatz, except by doing an expansion in perturbation theory.

Comment: @hft, no they are not.

Comment: @RudolfSmorka, i see so i guess its just a matter of guessing.

Comment: Coming up with the ansatz is a matter of guessing. However you should keep in mind two things. (1) There *are* some general principles you can use to make good guesses, like respecting the symmetry of the problem, calculating the correct asymptotic behavior, and using perturbation theory to motivate a guess. (2) Given two trial wavefunctions (such as yours and the book's), there *is* a way to see which ansatz is better -- the one that leads to the lowest value for the ground state energy when you run it through the variational method machinery.

Comment: @Andrew that condition makes sense, but how can i know apriori which of the two to use is my main concern

Comment: That should boil down to the asymptotics. At large $x$, the $1/x$ potential will dominate. That looks like a Coloumb potential, so I'd expect the dominant long-distance behavior to be like the Hydrogen ground state wavefunction, $\sim e^{-a x}$.

Comment: Yes, it is usually important to capture the correct long distance behaviour (unless the long distance behaviour is guaranteed to be an unimportant small correction, in which case the mid-to-long distance behaviour is the one to cover), and there are ways to extract that behaviour without a full solution. Then you will be able to guess an ansatz.

Comment: The problem doesn’t state whether the domain is $0\le x<\infty$ or $-\infty<x<\infty$?

Comment: I suspect you missed something in the description of the problem. The range should be given in the text of the problem, not in the solution. As is, it sounds suspicious that the range could be from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$: for positive $b$, the potential would correspond to an attraction for positive $x$ and repulsion for negative $x$. Moreover, both wavefunctions in your question wouldn't be ground state wavefunctions, due to the presence of a node at the origin.